# Run logit regression in r

Tags: r, regression, glm

I am trying to run a probit regression in R.
I am wondering which function suits best for it.

I had a look at the glm function. Am I right with this?
For example, does the output of the following code give the result of a probit regression with fixed effects in the "spieler"-level?:

```
probTc = glm(Esieg~TTRverf+ factor(spieler),family = "binomial", data = datregT)
```

Comment: For starters you can consult `?glm` and `?family`.

Comment: You need to include option  `link="probit"`.

Comment: Hey :) 
Thanks for helping. Do I indeed take into account the fixed effects of the variable "spieler" with the term "factor(spieler)" ?